# How to break out of the python shell:

Tags: python-2.7, python

So I basically was fiddling with my python shell (python 2.7) and I typed the following

```
>>>type(''')
```

at which point regardless of what I do everything I type is treated like a string. What command will allow me to cause an error and return back to the normal shell, or even better, cleanly break and return to the normal shell?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You started a string value with the `'''` triple quote.

Use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> to break out of the input loop, or close the opening quotes and parenthesis with `''')`:

```
>>> type(''')
... Oops
... What now?
... ^C
  File "<stdin>", line 3
    What now?
            ^
SyntaxError: EOF while scanning triple-quoted string literal
>>> type(''')
... Or you can just close the string and function call!
... ''')
<type 'str'>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `CTRL-C`. Then, if you want to leave the python shell, you use `exit()`